# Missing EPSG Factory

Tags: java, geotools, epsg

When I using jar and osm file

the terminal show：

```
10:39:29.940 INFO (OpenStreetMapModule.java:171) Building street graph from OSM
Feb 14, 2017 10:39:30 AM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory isAvailable




 WARNING: Unavailable authority factory: European Petroleum Survey Group
    org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Failed to connect to the EPSG database.
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:441)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:821)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:815)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:516)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:455)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:88)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:257)
    at org.opentripplanner.common.geometry.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:41)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildBasicGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:615)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:238)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:172)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilder.run(GraphBuilder.java:157)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.run(OTPMain.java:111)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:86)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't read file "EPSG.zip".
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:313)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore0(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:397)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:434)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Geotools/Databases/HSQL/v7.9.0/EPSG_creation_lock.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.acquireLock(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:343)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:280)
    ... 24 more

Feb 14, 2017 10:39:30 AM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory isAvailable
WARNING: Unavailable authority factory: European Petroleum Survey Group
org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Failed to connect to the EPSG database.
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:441)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceImplementation(FactoryRegistry.java:437)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:365)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:145)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:220)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:440)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.LongitudeFirstFactory.createBackingStore(LongitudeFirstFactory.java:191)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:821)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:815)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:516)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:455)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:88)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:257)
    at org.opentripplanner.common.geometry.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:41)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildBasicGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:615)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:238)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:172)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilder.run(GraphBuilder.java:157)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.run(OTPMain.java:111)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:86)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't read file "EPSG.zip".
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:313)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore0(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:397)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:434)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Geotools/Databases/HSQL/v7.9.0/EPSG_creation_lock.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.acquireLock(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:343)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:280)
    ... 35 more

Feb 14, 2017 10:39:30 AM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory isAvailable
WARNING: Unavailable authority factory: European Petroleum Survey Group
org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Failed to connect to the EPSG database.
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:441)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:226)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:220)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:440)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.LongitudeFirstFactory.createBackingStore(LongitudeFirstFactory.java:191)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:821)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:815)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:516)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:455)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:88)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:257)
    at org.opentripplanner.common.geometry.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:41)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildBasicGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:615)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:238)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:172)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilder.run(GraphBuilder.java:157)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.run(OTPMain.java:111)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:86)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't read file "EPSG.zip".
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:313)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore0(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:397)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:434)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Geotools/Databases/HSQL/v7.9.0/EPSG_creation_lock.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.acquireLock(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:343)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:280)
    ... 33 more

Feb 14, 2017 10:39:30 AM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory isAvailable
WARNING: Unavailable authority factory: European Petroleum Survey Group
org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Failed to connect to the EPSG database.
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:441)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:821)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:815)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:516)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:455)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:102)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:257)
    at org.opentripplanner.common.geometry.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:41)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildBasicGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:615)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:238)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:172)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilder.run(GraphBuilder.java:157)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.run(OTPMain.java:111)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:86)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't read file "EPSG.zip".
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:313)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore0(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:397)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:434)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Geotools/Databases/HSQL/v7.9.0/EPSG_creation_lock.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.acquireLock(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:343)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:280)
    ... 24 more

Feb 14, 2017 10:39:30 AM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory isAvailable
WARNING: Unavailable authority factory: European Petroleum Survey Group
org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Failed to connect to the EPSG database.
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:441)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceImplementation(FactoryRegistry.java:437)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:365)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:145)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:220)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:440)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.LongitudeFirstFactory.createBackingStore(LongitudeFirstFactory.java:191)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:821)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:815)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:516)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:455)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:102)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:257)
    at org.opentripplanner.common.geometry.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:41)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildBasicGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:615)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:238)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:172)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilder.run(GraphBuilder.java:157)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.run(OTPMain.java:111)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:86)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't read file "EPSG.zip".
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:313)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore0(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:397)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:434)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Geotools/Databases/HSQL/v7.9.0/EPSG_creation_lock.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.acquireLock(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:343)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:280)
    ... 35 more

Feb 14, 2017 10:39:30 AM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory isAvailable
WARNING: Unavailable authority factory: European Petroleum Survey Group
org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Failed to connect to the EPSG database.
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:441)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:226)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:220)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:440)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.LongitudeFirstFactory.createBackingStore(LongitudeFirstFactory.java:191)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:821)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:815)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:516)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:455)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:102)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:257)
    at org.opentripplanner.common.geometry.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:41)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildBasicGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:615)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:238)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:172)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilder.run(GraphBuilder.java:157)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.run(OTPMain.java:111)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:86)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't read file "EPSG.zip".
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:313)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore0(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:397)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:434)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Geotools/Databases/HSQL/v7.9.0/EPSG_creation_lock.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.acquireLock(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:343)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:280)
    ... 33 more

10:39:30.189 ERROR (GeometryUtils.java:43) Unable to create longitude-first WGS84 CRS
org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:4326" from authority "EPSG" found for object of type "EngineeringCRS".
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CartesianAuthorityFactory.noSuchAuthorityException(CartesianAuthorityFactory.java:136) ~[otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CartesianAuthorityFactory.createEngineeringCRS(CartesianAuthorityFactory.java:130) ~[otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CartesianAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(CartesianAuthorityFactory.java:121) ~[otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AuthorityFactoryAdapter.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(AuthorityFactoryAdapter.java:801) ~[otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ThreadedAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(ThreadedAuthorityFactory.java:731) ~[otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:179) ~[otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.opentripplanner.common.geometry.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:41) ~[otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildBasicGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:615) [otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:238) [otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:172) [otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilder.run(GraphBuilder.java:157) [otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.run(OTPMain.java:111) [otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:86) [otp-1.0.0-shaded.jar:1.1]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildBasicGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:615)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule$Handler.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:238)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.module.osm.OpenStreetMapModule.buildGraph(OpenStreetMapModule.java:172)
    at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilder.run(GraphBuilder.java:157)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.run(OTPMain.java:111)
    at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:86)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create longitude-first WGS84 coordinate reference system.
    at org.opentripplanner.common.geometry.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:44)
    ... 6 more
```

but If I change computer I can run it so I guess it seem configure error but I don't solve it.

Comment: where did the jar come from? if it is yours then please show us how you built it (pom.xml dependencies)

Comment: For me the problem in a Tomcat was the non-existing temp directory, where HSQL database is extracted

Answer (score 2):

The root issue is that GeoTools is unable to find the EPSG database where it expects to (`/tmp/Geotools/Databases/HSQL/v7.9.0/`). This usually means that you have not included the `gt-epsg-hsql` module in your jar.

It will possibly work on a computer where a previous GeoTools program has unpacked the database as GeoTools leaves the copy in place to save time the next time it is run, but would fail on another computer.

Comment: when I rm -rf  /tmp/Geotools/ the jar can run success

Comment: might be a permissions problem

Answer (score 0):

On my case the order of dependencies is the key , this is my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-wkt</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geometry</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```